# Need regular expression pattern to get the distinguished name separated?

Tags: c#, .net, regex, c#-4.0

Following string contains multiple distinguished names joined by semicolon. I need the regular expression pattern to get the distinguished name separated.

```
"CN=s\,tttrrr,OU=OU1,DC=dom1,DC=local;CN=g\;hi\,klm,OU=OU1,DC=dom1,DC=local;CN=rrr\ttt,OU=OU1,DC=dom1,DC=local;CN=Vvvv,OU=OU1,DC=dom1,DC=local"
```

Result in need:

```
CN=s\,tttrrr,OU=OU1,DC=dom1,DC=local
CN=g\;hi\,klm,OU=OU1,DC=dom1,DC=local
CN=rrr\ttt,OU=OU1,DC=dom1,DC=local
CN=Vvvv,OU=OU1,DC=dom1,DC=local
```

Comment: @KonradKokosa, except for the second line, where he wants to keep a semicolon.

Comment: and what have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do a [`Regex.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8yttk7sy(v=vs.110).aspx) on the semi-colons but exclude backslash-escaped ones using a [Zero-width negative lookbehind assertion.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx#grouping_constructs) - basically check for stuff before the semi-colon that doesn't match a `\`, but don't include it in the split.

This is of the form `(?<!pattern)` and you want this to match but ignore a backslash `[\\]`, then lastly match the semicolon, so the full pattern becomes `@"(?<![\\]);"`:

```
string dn = @"CN=s\,tttrrr,OU=OU1,DC=dom1,DC=local;CN=g\;hi\,klm,OU=OU1,DC=dom1,DC=local;CN=rrr\ttt,OU=OU1,DC=dom1,DC=local;CN=Vvvv,OU=OU1,DC=dom1,DC=local";

string[] vals = Regex.Split(dn, @"(?<![\\]);");
foreach (var val in vals)
{
    Console.WriteLine(val);
}
```

Output:

- CN=s\,tttrrr,OU=OU1,DC=dom1,DC=local
- CN=g\;hi\,klm,OU=OU1,DC=dom1,DC=local
- CN=rrr\ttt,OU=OU1,DC=dom1,DC=local
- CN=Vvvv,OU=OU1,DC=dom1,DC=local

Answer (score 0):

Try this pattern `(?i:;)?([^>]+?local)`

Comment: What if it won't be `DC=local`?

Answer (score 0):

```
string input= @"CN=s\,tttrrr,OU=OU1,DC=dom1,DC=local;CN=g\;hi\,klm,OU=OU1,DC=dom1,DC=local;CN=rrr\ttt,OU=OU1,DC=dom1,DC=local;CN=Vvvv,OU=OU1,DC=dom1,DC=local";
Regex pattern = new Regex(@"(?<=local);");
string[] result = pattern.Split(input);
result.ToList().ForEach(a => Console.WriteLine(a));
```

output:

```
CN=s\,tttrrr,OU=OU1,DC=dom1,DC=local
CN=g\;hi\,klm,OU=OU1,DC=dom1,DC=local
CN=rrr\ttt,OU=OU1,DC=dom1,DC=local
CN=Vvvv,OU=OU1,DC=dom1,DC=local
```

Comment: What if it won't be `DC=local`?

Answer (score 0):

you could use this pattern

```
(CN=(?:(?!CN=).)*)(?:;|$)
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/kK2uX1/1)

or this pattern

```
(CN=(?:[^C]|C(?!N=))*)(?:;|$)
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/kK2uX1/2)